# How to add, save and show textarea and its value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a program to add students and student grades but anytime I change the student grade I want to add a `textarea` containing a comment why I changed the grade. I have added the comment in the right place like this :

```html
<tr class ="tr2">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
        Comment: 
        <textarea id="msg2" class="input" style="height: 20px; width: 200px;" runat="server"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I have no idea how to show it in my view and how to save it on the database. I have many grades from different students.

Comment: I am an intern and I am learning. If you don't want to help you don't have to comment

Comment: What you should do is to include an id and runat="server" for the Comment table row. You can default visibility to false; then set visible to true when the student grade changes. You have to look-up a tutorial for how to save in a database

Comment: @Vohuman this is some nobility from you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has to little information.
I'm just guessing.

1. On your student info table add this tr and on your ChangeStudenntGradeButton_OnClick event 
   , save the text from  msg2 to your database.
2. On the pageload read the info from database, based on studentID and populate msg2 (msg2.Text = '.....')

If you have more students on the same page then use a repeater.

Comment: If you are not sure, don't guess but ask!